# Music in Catalina doesn’t remember window size

Tags: itunes, catalina, window-manager, music.app

Each time I open the Music app in macOS Catalina (10.15.1), the window size is set to maximum. I then have to rescale it down to fit my use case. But after it’s been quit and reopened, it is again huge. I find it silly to use Music at its biggest size on a 27” screen!

Am I alone in this? If so, are there any steps I can take to fix this?

Comment: I’ve exactly the same problem. While I wouldn’t really mind on a MacBook display, it gets quite annoying with display sizes beyond 24″. Unfortunately I haven’t found a solution or workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue and on 43" monitor - not much fun.

Solved by deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Music.plist`

Make sure to create a backup of that file first and optionally create screenshots of your settings as those will be lost.